# Android HealthConnect - Production

Tags: android, permissions, healthconnect

I have integrated HealthConncet into my Android application. I followed all steps and on debug everytying were working well. I did publish the app on GooglePlay and when I download the app from GooglePlayStore while trying to run permissions dialog I have following message:

> This app can't access Health Connect. Check the app is up-to-date, or
> contact the app developer for support

I am reading internet and google privacy policy. I checked my google play developer console for some privacy permissions but all seems to be valid.

Did anyone of you already played with integrating HealthConnect?

Comment: Can you share playstore link?

Comment: It`s been fixes after I apply below form and 2-3 weeks ;)

Comment: Oops, I wanted to test your app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apps currently need to be allowlisted to get access to Health Connect in production. You can follow the process outlined at: https://developer.android.com/guide/health-and-fitness/health-connect/frequently-asked-questions#q_how_do_i_request_access_to_readwrite_data_types

Answer (score -2):

The Recents screen (also referred to as the Overview screen, recent task list, or recent apps) is a system-level UI that lists recently accessed activities and tasks. The user can navigate through the list and select a task to resume, or the user can remove a task from the list by swiping it away.

The Recents screen uses a document-centric model—introduced in Android 5.0 (API level 21)—in which multiple instances of the same activity containing different documents may appear as tasks in the Recents screen. For example, Google Drive may have a task for each of several Google documents. Each document appears as a task in the Recents screen.

The Recents screen showing two Google Drive documents, each represented as a separate task.
Another common example is when the user is using their browser, and they tap Share > Gmail. The Gmail app's Compose screen appears. Tapping the Recents button at that time reveals Chrome and Gmail running as separate tasks.

Comment: I dont understand your answer